# Is 'I can't imagine what would that be like' a correct sentence?

Tags: american-english, british-english

> I don't like literary theory, I can't imagine what would that be
>   like..

That's my own sentence, but I've got no idea how to correct this.

Comment: Could you give context or what meaning you are trying to convey?

Comment: @ katatahito I was talking with my course mate, we were discussing the Literary Theory course and I'm quite bad at literature, the sentence was what I said, but I'm not even sure if it's okay or not.

Comment: I'm not sure how "I don't like X" and "I can't imagine what [it] (X) would be like" can both be true.

Answer (score 5):

In your comment you mention that the context is:

> I was talking with my course mate, we were discussing the Literary Theory course and I'm quite bad at literature, the sentence was what I said

In this case all you have to do is switch **would** and **that** to make:

> I don't like literary theory, I can't imagine what that would be like.